# How to get Color value from a json string and use it in Flutter Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a JSON assigned to a variable called **user**

```
 var user= {
'Name':'khan',
'Country':'Pakistan',
'color':'Color(0xffffff)',
};
```

Suppose I want to get data from it and use it somewhere.

```
 String encodedjson=jsonEncode(user);
    Map <String,dynamic> decodedJson=jsonDecode(encodedjson);
var colordata=decodedJson['color'];
```

Now I want to use **colordata**
Let say I want to put the color in a container  background

**i.e**

```
 Container(width: 200,height:200,color:colordata,)
```

This will give me an error because colordata is not the **type Color**..
So what should I do use JSON color like this.

Comment: Are you able to change what's stored in the JSON?

Comment: Yes, I can dot it in my actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the color as a hex literal/int, which is JSON encodable, then pass it to the `Color` constructor:

```
var user= {
'Name':'khan',
'Country':'Pakistan',
'color': 0xffffff,
};
String encodedjson=jsonEncode(user);
Map<String,dynamic> decodedJson=jsonDecode(encodedjson);
var colordata = Color(decodedJson['color']);
```

Comment: Actually, the change in a JSON is occuerd  using ColorPicker. void changeColor(Color color) {user['color']=color;}

Comment: @MehranUllah Could you rephrase what you said. It was not clear.

Comment: Actually, the change in a JSON is occuerd  using ColorPicker. void changeColor(Color color) {user['color']=color;}

Comment: @MehranUllah Then do `user['color']=color.value;`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more clarity if you have a a color like this:

```dart
    final whiteValue = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(Color(0xFFFFFFFF).value));
    print("COLOR VAL $whiteValue"); // prints 4294967295
    final newWhite = Color(whiteValue);
    print(newWhite); // prints Color(0xffffffff)
```

you want to encode the value property and then interpolate that in, hopefully this adds some clarity to what the above answer was getting at.